# New-ADUser is not working properly when bulk loading via .csv file

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory, bulk-load

I'm running into an error where this is not picking up the password field at all... I ran the import command manually to make sure it was grabbing all of the correct data, but it errors out on the password and group info...

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\NewUsers.csv"            
foreach ($User in $Users)            
    {            
    $Displayname = $User.'Firstname' + " " + $User.'Lastname'            
    $UserFirstname = $User.'Firstname'            
    $UserLastname = $User.'Lastname'            
    $OU = $User.'OU'            
    $SAM = $User.'SAM'            
    $UPN = $User.'Firstname' + "." + $User.'Lastname' + "@" + $User.'Maildomain'            
    $Password = $User.'Password'   
    $Description = $User.'Description'            
    $Group = $User.'Group'  

    $Account = New-ADUser -Name "$Displayname" -DisplayName "$Displayname" -SamAccountName $SAM -UserPrincipalName $UPN -GivenName "$UserFirstname" -Surname "$UserLastname" -Description "$Description" -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $true -Path "$OU" -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -PasswordNeverExpires $true -server esg.intl -PassThru   

    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $Account
    }
```

And here are the errors I'm getting even though I know the passwords are ok:

```
New-ADUser : The password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirement of the domain.
At C:\Users\A-Shane.Johnson\Desktop\Bulk Add Domain Users.ps1:24 char:13
+ ...  $Account = New-ADUser -Name "$Displayname" -DisplayName "$Displaynam ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (CN=ESGAP PMOInt...,DC=esg,DC=intl:String) [New-ADUser], ADPasswordComplexi
   tyException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1325,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Members'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\A-Shane.Johnson\Desktop\Bulk Add Domain Users.ps1:26 char:46
+     Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $Account
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGrou
   pMember
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how that CSV is generated you might try double checking that there isn't an extra space in the Password column header? i.e. 'Password '. Sometimes that trips me up because it doesn't show in the excel or cmd line view easily.

Comment: I checked and there is no extra space. And when I run the command to view the password it recognizes it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and answer. Apparently our domain has an issue when part of the username is in the password. I misunderstood that error thinking that the conversion is what was causing the issue...

I fixed the passwords and now the script runs beautifully!